# Codility Challenge

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm

I'm trying to finish the codility challenge to improve my programming skills or rather lack of it. The details of the challenge are here.

> In a room there are N ropes and N weights. Each rope is connected to
>   exactly one weight (at just one end), and each rope has a particular
>   durability − the maximum weight that it can suspend. There is also a
>   hook, attached to the ceiling. The ropes can be attached to the hook
>   by tying the end without the weight. The ropes can also be attached to
>   other weights; that is, the ropes and weights can be attached to one
>   another in a chain. A rope will break if the sum of weights connected
>   to it, directly or indirectly, is greater than its durability.
>
> We know the order in which we want to attach N ropes. More precisely,
>   we know the parameters of the rope (durability and weight) and the
>   position of each attachment. Durabilities, weights and positions are
>   given in three zero-indexed arrays A, B, C of lengths N. For each I (0
>   ≤ I < N): A[I] is the durability of the I-th rope, B[I] is the weight
>   connected to the I-th rope, C[I] (such that C[I] < I) is the position
>   to which we attach the I-th rope; if C[I] equals −1 we attach to the
>   hook, otherwise we attach to the weight connected to the C[I]-th rope.
>   The goal is to find the maximum number of ropes that can be attached
>   in the specified order without breaking any of the ropes. Write a
>   function: def solution(A, B, C) that, given three zero-indexed arrays
>   A, B, C of N integers, returns the maximum number of ropes that can be
>   attached in a given order. For example,  Given the following arrays:
>
> ```
> A= [4,3,1]
> B = [2,2,1]
> C = [-1,0,1]
> ```
>
> the function should return 2, as if we attach a third rope then one rope will break, because the sum of weights is greater than its
>   durability (2 + 2 + 1 = 5 and 5 > 4).

Here is my attempted solution below. I have a helper function called add_weights which returns True if adding the latest rope does not cause any other rope to break and false otherwise.

```
def add_weights(A, ancestors, weights, weight, rope):
    #add weight(int) to rope and ancestors
    if (rope == -1):
        return (True)
    else:
        weights[rope] += weight
        if (A[rope] < weights[rope]):
            print "Rope that breaks", rope
            return False
        ancestor = ancestors[rope]
        print ancestor
        add_weights(A, ancestors, weights, weight, ancestor)




def solution(A, B, C):
    # write your code in Python 2.7
    weights = {}
    ancestors = {}
    for i in range(len(B)):
        weights[i] = B[i]
    for i in range(len(C)):
        #attaching rope i to rope x
        x = C[i]
        ancestors[i] = x
        broke = add_weights(A, ancestors, weights, B[i], x)
        if (not broke):
            return i
    return len(C)
```

The problem is during the second iteration of the for loop in the function solution(when I'm trying add rope 1),  the variable break somehow evaluates to None, when I can clearly see add_weights returning True. I have tested it with a debugger as well, so I'm not entirely sure what's going on. Any help is welcome.

Comment: Please do come up with a better question title; your current one tells us nothing about your problem. It doesn't matter to us where your problem originates from.

Comment: `add_weights` only has a `return` in the base case - make the last line `return add_weights(...)`.

Comment: I still want to know why the answer is 2 in their example.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Exercise5_DurablityofRopes
{
    class Program
    {
           static int[] A_Durability = new int[] { 15, 6, 2,3,1 };
           static int[] B_Weight = new int[] { 2, 1, 2,3,1 };
           static int[] C_Position = new int[] { -1, 0, 1 ,2,3};
           static int no_of_ropes_attached = 0;
           static int maxropeattached = 0;
           static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           // first position cannot necessarily be -1 hence Checking for each position How many maximum ropes can be attached
            for (int i = 0; i <= C_Position.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                int[] Copy_Durability = new int[A_Durability.Length];
                for (int l = 0; l <= C_Position.Length - 1; l++)
                {
                    Copy_Durability[l] = A_Durability[l];
                }
                AddNextRope(i, B_Weight[i], Copy_Durability);          
                Console.WriteLine("Total Number of ropes can be attached to " + C_Position[i] + " ropes are" + no_of_ropes_attached);
                if (no_of_ropes_attached>=maxropeattached)
                {
                    maxropeattached = no_of_ropes_attached;
                }
                no_of_ropes_attached = 0;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Total Number of ropes can be attached is  " + maxropeattached);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void AddNextRope(int currentRopePosition,int newWeight,int[] Durability)
        {
            if (currentRopePosition == C_Position.Length - 1) return;
            // decrease same amount of weight from all ansestors from their durability and check if any of them breaks (durability <0) with new weight added
            for (int k = currentRopePosition; k != 0; k--)
            {
                Durability[k] = Durability[k] - newWeight;
                if(Durability[k]<0)
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
            no_of_ropes_attached = no_of_ropes_attached + 1; 

            for (int i = 0; i <= C_Position.Length - 1; i++)
                {
                    if (C_Position[i] == C_Position[currentRopePosition] + 1)
                    {
                        if (A_Durability[i] > B_Weight[i])
                        {
                            AddNextRope(i, B_Weight[i], Durability);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was my first solution O(N**2), it simply runs trought the ropes and reduces the weight to each connected one.

```py
  def solution(A, B, C):
    num_ropes = len(C)

    for i in range(num_ropes):
      node = i
      while(node != -1):
        A[node] -= B[i]
        if A[node] < 0:
          return i
        node = C[node]
    return num_ropes
```

This is the O(N*log(N)) solution, the principle is that instead of going trought all the ropes, it goes trought groups of ropes that have one tension.

```py
  def solution(A, B, C):
    num_ropes = len(C)

    for i in range(num_ropes):
      A[i] -= B[i]
      if A[i] < 0:
        return i

      pre_node = C[i]
      while pre_node != -1:
        A[pre_node] -= B[i]
        if A[pre_node] < 0:
          return i

        if A[pre_node] <= A[i]:
          C[i] = pre_node
          A[i] = A[pre_node]
        pre_node = C[pre_node]

    return num_ropes
```

It can be tested using this last part or at https://app.codility.com/programmers/challenges/sulphur2014/

```py
  if __name__ == '__main__':
    A = [5, 3, 6, 3, 3]
    B = [2, 3, 1, 1, 2]
    C = [-1, 0, -1, 0, 3]
    assert solution(A, B, C) == 3

    A = [4, 3, 1]
    B = [2, 2, 1]
    C = [-1, 0, 1]
    assert solution(A, B, C) == 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have time to translate this into Python but you can have an idea by look at this JS code:

```
function keysOrderedByValues(array) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        result[array[i] + 1] = i;
    }
    return result;
}

function findFirstPositiveElem(array) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i]>0) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

function accumulativeArray(array) {
    var result = [];
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        sum = sum + array[i];
        result.push(sum);
    }
    return result;
}

Array.prototype.indexedByArray = function(array) {
    result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        result.push(this[array[i]])
    }
    return result;
}

function test(ds, ws, ords) {
    return findFirstPositiveElem(ws.indexedByArray(keysOrderedByValues(ords)), ds);
}

console.log(test([4,3,1], [2,2,1], [-1,0,1]))
```

Answer (score -1):

Forgot to mention: this is O(n) and some space complexity for the array B2

```
    int Solution (int[]A, int[] B, int[] C)
    {
        if (A==null || B==null || C==null)
            return -1;
        if (A.Length==0 || B.Length==0 || C.Length==0)
            return -1;
        if (A.Length != B.Length && A.Length != C.Length)
            return -1;


        var bLen=B.Count();
        var B2 = new int[bLen];
        for (int i = 0; i < bLen; i++)
            B2[i]=(i==0? 0 : B2[i-1]) + B[i]; //cumulative sum


        var ret=-1;
        var skip=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < A.Length; i++)
        {
            skip=C[i]+1;
            if (A[i] - (B2[bLen-1] - (skip>0 ? B2[skip-1] : 0)) < 0) 
            {
                ret=bLen-skip-1;
                break;
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

Comment: This solution did not work for me in case. 
`A=[5, 3, 6, 3, 3]
B=[2, 3, 1, 1, 2]
C=[-1, 0, -1, 0, 3]`. Returning 4 ropes instead of 3 ropes.
I also had to change `B.Count()` into `B.Length`.